# Force a select to be wide enough to display selected element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Say I define the following table with a select control in bootstrap:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td style="width: 95%;"></td>    
<td>
<select class="selectpicker form-control" name="filterBy">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">All Ages</option>
    <option value="32">0-3 Years</option>
    <option value="33">3-6 Years</option>
    <option value="34">6-9 Years</option>
    <option value="35">9-12 Years</option>
    <option value="36">12-15 Years</option>
    <option value="37">15-18 Years</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How can I force the select to be just large enough such that the full text "All Ages" is completely visible?

Using bootstrap 3.3.7

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bothered about the dimension of other `td` whose width is set to 95%, you can use `width: max-content;` for `.selectpicker` it will take maximum width based on its children needs.

```css
.selectpicker{
width: max-content !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
<tr>
<td style="width: 95%;"></td>    
<td>
<select class="selectpicker form-control" name="filterBy">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">All Ages</option>
    <option value="32">0-3 Years</option>
    <option value="33">3-6 Years</option>
    <option value="34">6-9 Years</option>
    <option value="35">9-12 Years</option>
    <option value="36">12-15 Years</option>
    <option value="37">15-18 Years</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps